# Сортировка массива по вертикали

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Как отсортировать массив в виде строки,

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8
```

по вертикали

```
0 3 6 
1 4 7 
2 5 8
```

Матрица для наглядности.

Comment: А кто за закрытие? Почему? Вроде, нормальный вопрос. И код не нужен, потому что вопрос на алгоритмы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Разрезаем строку по символу-разделителю на части.
2. Считаем количество частей. Берём из него квадратный корень, округляем до ближайшего большего целого. Это число (N) будет размерностью матрицы.
3. Создаём массив размера *NxN* и построчно заполняем его частями строки. Если часть массива осталась незаполненной, в незаполненные ячейки записываем какой-нибудь специальный маркер.
4. Собираем строку из массива, пробегая его по столбцам (а не по строкам, как при заполнении). Если наткнулись на маркер, ячейку пропускаем.

P.S. Если гарантируется, что число элементов всегда квадрат целого числа, то можно обойтись без округления квадратного корня и без маркера.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле речь идёт о транспонировании двумерной матрицы, представленной одномерным массивом.
Если матрица квадратная и количество элементов строки равно **n**, это можно сделать по формуле

**T<sub>in+j</sub> = A<sub>jn+i</sub>, где i=0..n-1, j=0..n-1**